# Doubt on the meaning of $\| f \|_{[a,b]}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

is $\| f \|_{[a,b]}$ any norm associated to $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$?

Can I consider $$\| f \|_{[a,b]}=\int_a^b \lvert f(x) \lvert \ dx $$

or

$$\| f \|_{[a,b]}=\max_{x \in [a,b]} \lvert f(x) \lvert  $$?

Is there another definition of $\| f \|_{[a,b]}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of, e.g.

$$\|f\|_{[a,b],L^p}:=\left(\int_a^b |f(x)|^p\,\mathrm dx\right)^{\frac 1p}.$$

You have to specify the norm, as in infinitely dimensional vector spaces, they are not necessarily equivalent.